# Gitlab CI runner can't login into Nexus from non-master branch

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a Gitlab for my CI and a Nexus repository to push my docker images. From master Branch, I can login successfully, but when I try to login from Develop branch with the same credential, Gitlab runner can't log in.
This is my Gitlab CI console:

```
$ docker login -u $CI_USER -p $CI_PASS http://192.168.160.188:9050/
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `winpty docker login` (documented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248455/gitlab-runner-local-build-login-from-non-tty-device) if you're on a Windows 10 OS.  I had the same issue.

Comment: My Gitlab runner is on Oracle Linux